# Inheritance hierarchy and startsWith

Tags: arangodb

I'm an ArangoDB beginner and am trying to implement an inheritance hierarchy in documents - might end up being a car crash! Anyway I'm a little stuck. For example, if I had a number of documents like {type: animal.person} and {type: animal.dog} how would I find all documents with a type that startsWith animal in AQL?

I've tried to filter on 'type LIKE animal%' but it's slow.
I've tried to filter on 'CONTAINS(type, animal)' which is faster but guess that if for some reason I ever had a document like {type: xxx.animal.person} it would hit on that too. Also, the CONTAINS doesn't use an index.
I've also read a lot about skiplist indexes and using something like 'type >= animal' and 'type < animal' but for the life of me I can't figure it out - especially because of the dot!

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: It looks like you store strings like `{maintype}.{subtype}`. Any reason to do so instead of splitting it up into two separate attributes? That would allow you to search for exact equality, like `FILTER doc.type.maintype == "animal"` using a hash index for instance. A range search finding everything that starts with "animal" would require the conditions `type >= "animal" && type < "animam"`, or if you want "animal." to be the prefix, then it would be `type >= "animal." && type < "animal/"`(the last character in the 2nd condition is the char code plus 1, e.g. 46 for "." + 1 = 47, which is "/").

Comment: Thank you! The range search you suggested worked perfectly! I'm not splitting into separate attributes because I don't know how deep the hierarchy is i.e. how many dots there could be. I could split the string and store in an array if that could be searched quicker?

Comment: That would probably be the best solution, combined with a hash array index. You can even split the string with AQL, `SPLIT(type, ".")` on insertion. You could then utilize the index with `FILTER "animal" IN doc.type`, with type being like `["animal","dog"]` and the index `type[*]`.